# How did FB intelligently notify me of status update?

Tags: facebook, notifications, status

This evening my mom (we are listed as mom/close friend) made an update: "I went with Mike to go see Prometheus". I received notification of this status update, despite her not putting my FB name. How did the app discern that I was the "Mike" she referred to?

I posted no status update regarding our outing. I was not tagged by name or location. I must be missing something, this is a bit too creepy.

Thanks,

MNM

Comment: Hi, Michael, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not Facebook support. This is a question you should ask [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help) (you won't get an answer, but at least you'll be asking in the right place).

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 0):

You get notifications for every status update by your close friend, If she update `I was i with ABC` even then you will get notification that she update a status...